# java.lang.NullPointerException using MRUnit. Custom key serialization error

Tags: serialization, hadoop, nullpointerexception, mapreduce, mrunit

I'm trying to test a simple MapReduce project using MRUnit. I set the input for the mapDriver and then call `mapDriver.runTest()` (I've also tried with `mapDriver.run()` but produces the same error).

I have written a custom key which overloads the `write(DataOutput out)`, `readFields(DataInput in)` and `compareTo(...)` Methods. When debugging, the Key correctly writes its data using `write(DataOutput out)`. However, after the key's `readFields(DataInput in)` method (which correctly retrieves the data that was previously written using `write(DataOutput out)`) finishes, the error below is thrown.

I have searched on here for similar posts and have tried overriding the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods to no avail. Does MRUnit require any additional methods to be overriden when using custom keys? This post is most similar to [MRUnit with Avro NullPointerException in Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230482/mrunit-with-avro-nullpointerexception-in-serialization). However, I am not using avro, and as far as I am aware, I am using default serialization. Cheers!

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.Serialization.copy(Serialization.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.Serialization.copy(Serialization.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.mock.MockContextWrapper$4.answer(MockContextWrapper.java:78)
at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.StubbedInvocationMatcher.answer(StubbedInvocationMatcher.java:31)
at org.mockito.internal.MockHandler.handle(MockHandler.java:97)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.MethodInterceptorFilter.intercept(MethodInterceptorFilter.java:47)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper$Context$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$f555e120.write(<generated>)
at model.RMSEEvaluation$Mapper.map(RMSEEvaluation.java:57)
at model.RMSEEvaluation$Mapper.map(RMSEEvaluation.java:1)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.MapDriver.run(MapDriver.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.MapDriverBase.runTest(MapDriverBase.java:150)
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.TestDriver.runTest(TestDriver.java:137)
at test.TestRMSEEvaluation.testSetValues(TestRMSEEvaluation.java:77)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Can you post code for your key & the version of Hadoop + MRUnit you're using

Comment: Hi Chris, I've found the reason for the error and have posted an answer. I'm using [Hadoop 2.0.0-alpha](http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html#23+May%2C+2012%3A+Release+2.0.0-alpha+available) and [MRUnit 0.9.0-incubating-hadoop2](http://mrunit.apache.org/general/downloads.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution to this error. The error was because the type of serialization had not been set in the `Configuration` for `MapDriver mapDriver`. I had to explicitly set the serialization using the following:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("io.serializations","org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.JavaSerialization," 
            + "org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization");
mapDriver.setConfiguration(conf);
```

Hope this helps anyone with a similar problem!

Comment: This does not solve the problem.. Can you please help what you did here?

Answer (score 1):

First it's worth to [test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13288750/1050422) whether the serialization / deserialization works really as expected.
Without knowing how you wrote the test, the following simple one works well with [MRUnit 0.9.0-incubating](http://mrunit.apache.org/) and JUnit 4.10 :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.MapDriver;
import org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.MapReduceDriver;
import org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.ReduceDriver;
import org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.types.Pair;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestCustom {

    private MapDriver<CustomRecord, Text, CustomRecord, Text> mapDriver;

    private Mapper<CustomRecord, Text, CustomRecord, Text> map = 
        new Mapper<CustomRecord, Text, CustomRecord, Text>();

    private Reducer<CustomRecord, Text, CustomRecord, Text> reduce = 
        new Reducer<CustomRecord, Text, CustomRecord, Text>();

    private ReduceDriver<CustomRecord, Text, CustomRecord, Text> reduceDriver
        = ReduceDriver.newReduceDriver(reduce);

    private MapReduceDriver<CustomRecord, Text, CustomRecord, 
      Text, CustomRecord, Text> mapReduceDriver;

    private Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    //test data
    private Pair<CustomRecord, Text> data;

    //shuffled and sorted data
    private static List<Pair<CustomRecord, List<Text>>> shuffledData; 

    @Before
    public void init() {

        mapDriver = MapDriver.newMapDriver(map);
        mapReduceDriver = MapReduceDriver.newMapReduceDriver(map, reduce);
        mapDriver.withConfiguration(conf);
        initData();
    }

    private void initData() {

        CustomRecord key = new CustomRecord("first", 1);
        Text value = new Text("key1");
        data = new Pair<CustomRecord, Text>(key, value);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMapper() throws IOException {

        mapDriver.withInput(data);
        //expected output result
        mapDriver.withOutput(data); 
        mapDriver.runTest(true);

        //shuffle and sort
        List<Pair<CustomRecord, Text>> pairs = 
          new ArrayList<Pair<CustomRecord, Text>>();
        pairs.add(data);

        shuffledData = mapReduceDriver.shuffle(pairs);

    }

    @Test
    public void testReducer() throws IOException {

        // feed input to one single reduce call
        Pair<CustomRecord, List<Text>> pair = shuffledData.get(0);
        reduceDriver.withInput(pair.getFirst(), pair.getSecond());

        //reducer's output
        List<Pair<CustomRecord, Text>> result = reduceDriver.run();

        Assert.assertEquals("Key mismatch!", 
          data.getFirst(), result.get(0).getFirst());
        Assert.assertEquals("Value mismatch!", 
          data.getSecond(), result.get(0).getSecond());
    }
}
```

It tests the identity mapper and reducer with custom Writable as key (*CustomRecord*).
Note, that the key implements [WritableComparable](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparable.html), and overrides hashCode and equals.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, my key does implement [WritableComparable](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparable.html), and overrides hashCode and equals. I've actually found the reason why I was producing this error so will post a reply.