# Store and retrieve string arrays in HBase

Tags: serialization, hbase

I've read this answer ([How to store complex objects into hadoop Hbase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086684/how-to-store-complex-objects-into-hadoop-hbase?answertab=votes#tab-top)) regarding the storing of string arrays with HBase.

There it is said to use the `ArrayWritable` Class to serialize the array. With `WritableUtils.toByteArray(Writable ... writable)` I'll get a `byte[]` which I can store in HBase.

When I now try to retrieve the rows again, I get a `byte[]` which I have somehow to transform back again into an `ArrayWritable`.
But I don't find a way to do this. Maybe you know an answer or am I doing fundamentally wrong serializing my `String[]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may apply the following method to get back the `ArrayWritable` (taken from my earlier answer, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13288750/1050422)) .

```
public static <T extends Writable> T asWritable(byte[] bytes, Class<T> clazz)
            throws IOException {
        T result = null;
        DataInputStream dataIn = null;
        try {
            result = clazz.newInstance();
            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            dataIn = new DataInputStream(in);
            result.readFields(dataIn);
        }
        catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // should not happen
            assert false;
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // should not happen
            assert false;
        }
        finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(dataIn);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This method just deserializes the byte array to the correct object type, based on the provided class type token.
E.g:
Let's assume you have a custom ArrayWritable:

```
public class TextArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable {
    public TextArrayWritable() {
      super(Text.class);
    }
}
```

Now you issue a single HBase get:

```
...
Get get = new Get(row);
Result result = htable.get(get);
byte[] value = result.getValue(family, qualifier);
TextArrayWritable tawReturned = asWritable(value, TextArrayWritable.class);
Text[] texts = (Text[]) tawReturned.toArray();
for (Text t : texts) {
  System.out.print(t + " ");
}
...
```

Note:
You may have already found the [readCompressedStringArray()](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.23.6/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableUtils.html#readCompressedStringArray%28java.io.DataInput%29) and [writeCompressedStringArray()](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.23.6/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableUtils.html#writeCompressedByteArray%28java.io.DataOutput,%20byte%5B%5D%29) methods in WritableUtils
which seem to be suitable if you have your own String array-backed Writable class. 
Before using them, I'd warn you that these can cause serious performance hit due to
the overhead caused by the gzip compression/decompression.

Comment: Can you please help me on this one. I'm really new to HBase and guide me with easy steps. Thank YOu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236547/how-to-store-primitive-datatypes-strings-in-a-hbase-column-and-retrieve-them-u