# HBase arrays and Hive

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to write Arrays into HBase using Hadoop's ArrayWritable class. I'm serializing a List into ArrayWritable, and then use WritableUtils.toByteArray to get bytes. While reading, I reconstruct List from ArrayWritable. Have added the code for this operation below. I'm able to correctly read/write List into the HBase DB.

However, when we try to create an external table on top of the written data, we're not able to see the stored arrays in the expected format. The list of strings appear as concatenated strings without any separator, and certainly not as Arrays or Strings.

**PROBLEM**: We need the HBase arrays to be visible in Hive in a feasible format that we can use. We'll also be exporting this data for querying to Redshift, and hence need something workable. How can I modify my read/write approach so that it works for both Java application and Hive/Redshift.

Method used for serialization and de-serialization:

```
public static ArrayWritable getWritableFromArray(List<String> stringList) {
    Writable[] writables = new Writable[stringList.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < writables.length; i++) {
        writables[i] = new Text(stringList.get(i));
    }

    return new ArrayWritable(Text.class, writables);
}

public static List<String> getListFromWritable(ArrayWritable arrayWritable) {
    Writable[] writables = arrayWritable.get();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(writables.length);
    for (Writable writable : writables) {
        list.add(((Text) writable).toString());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Method for creating Hive table:

```
create external table testdata(
uid bigint
,city array<string>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe'
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key, d:city")
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "testdata");
```

Querying from Hive table returns this:

```
select * from testdata;
OK
23821975838576221       ["\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0006raipur\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"]
808554262192775221      ["\u0000\u0000\u0000","\u0006indore\u0006raipur\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"]
2361689275801875221     ["\u0000\u0000\u0000","\u0006indore\u0006raipur\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"]
4897772799782875221     ["\u0000\u0000\u0000","\nchandigarh\u0006indore\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"]
```

When this data is exported to Redshift, the cities appear concatenated, as

```
indoreraipur
chandigarhindore
```

How can I fix this? Is trying to write a List directly into HBase a bad idea? Should I try to manually serialize and deserialize it and write it as a String instead of an Array type?

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064171/store-and-retrieve-string-arrays-in-hbase.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't really answer my problem; it mostly explains how to store arrays in HBase, which is pretty much the above code.